# get file path for action GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, file, uri

**I know I am asking the question which is already asked lots of time but I have tried lots of answer from them.**

I have developed below code for taking pdf files and I have setup PROVIDER perfectly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

but once I will get data on `onActivityResult`then trying to get file path.

So In a few cases, I am getting file path proper. But in Samsung device, I am getting URI as `content://file-content/number`. So due to this type of URI, method can't convert that URI to file path.

Here is my method which converts URI to localPath

```
private static String getRealPath(ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri uri, String whereClause) {
        String localPath = "";

        // Query the URI with the condition.
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, whereClause, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            boolean moveToFirst = cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (moveToFirst) {

                // Get column name by URI type.
                String columnName = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;

                if (uri == MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) {
                    columnName = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
                } else if (uri == MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) {
                    columnName = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
                } else if (uri == MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) {
                    columnName = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
                }

                // Get column index.
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);

                // Get column value which is the uri related file local path.
                localPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
        }

        return localPath;
    }
```

So I have two question about this problem :

1. I want to get column name for URI but Not getting which type of URI when user select file from Drive's file.

   *i.e: In my method, I can't compare 
      uri == MediaStore.Image.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.*
2. How can convert `content://file-content/number` uri to file path.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get column name for uri but Not getting which type of URI
>   when user select file from Drive's file.

Use this code to check scheme of an URI:

```
if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
    // Content scheme        
} else if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE)){
   // File scheme    
} else {
   // Other
}
```

> How can convert content://file-content/number uri to file path.

Create a temp file:

```
@Nullable
private File createTempUploadFile(String fileName) {
    File storageDir = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "Upload");
    if (storageDir.exists()) {
        File[] files = storageDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            file.delete();
        }
    } else {
        if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    File file = new File(storageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);
    mCurrentFilePath = "file:" + file.getAbsolutePath();
    return file;
}
```

Write a util method to copy from an input stream to a file

```
public static boolean copyFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream, File dest) {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024]; // 64KB
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Timber.e(e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

Copy content from the URI to the temp file in `onActivityResult`

```
try {
    File dest = createTempUploadFile(fileName);
    if (dest != null) {
        InputStream inputStream =
                getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        Utils.copyFileFromInputStream(inputStream, dest);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO
}
```

Now get the file path from the temp file.

**Update:** If you want to get file name from a URI, use this code inside `onActivityResult`.

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String fileName = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex);
    }  
} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup thanks you saved my day. but my question is that how can I get filename to pass into `createTempUploadFile` function!

Comment: getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); is responding no such file or directory found.

Comment: getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); is responding me "no such file or directory found".

Comment: Cam you use logcat to see file uri full path. I need to see it to find root cause.

Comment: I am getting uri = "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DdNqhIYs1Zum600Gx_CbFQcRywYkUEsmKhxXlurrwt5HZh9_c%0A".. Now if I am trying to transfer `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` then logcat shows me  is responding me "no such file or directory found"

Comment: Please add this to intent that you want to open file `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);`. And make sure you add read/write external permissions in manifest and grant all.

Comment: @NhấtGiang how much temporary is this file? I try to open it from other activity and I get FileException: no such file or directory found